# Use localization in .cshtml razor template using RazorLightEngine

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

I'm using RazorLightEngine to transform .cshtml files (templates) into html that I can use in emails.

I would like to add localization to these templates.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) talks about how to do this for views, but I'm not sure how to implement this for just rendering templates as strings.

Comment: It seems `RazorLightEngine` has not implemented localizaion. Check [IViewLocalizer in cshtml template #166](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/166)